# How can I list running bash scripts by the name of the script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, process, ps

`ps` returns `bash` as the name of the process... I would like the name of the shell script instead.

For instance, if my script is `TestEric.sh`, I would like to list the number of instances of that script currently running.

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that `ps` by default only shows the base command in its output, not the whole command line including arguments.

If you launch your script with `bash TestEric.sh`, the base command is `bash`. If you run it as `TestEric.sh` (possibly including its path), the base command will be that and not bash.

---

You can easily use `pgrep` instead of `ps` to list processes filtered by name. It has a `-f` flag that makes it match the given pattern against the whole command line instead of just the base command.

The `-a` flag makes it display that whole command line in its output for debugging purposes instead of just the PID. Once you verified it works, you can/should remove it again in your script.

Try this:

```
pgrep -f -a TestEric.sh
```

You can later count the processes using `wc` by counting the `pgrep` output lines:

```
pgrep -f TestEric.sh | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try running `ps u` instead. From the man pages, the u option corresponds to `display user-oriented format` which will display both the shell used to run the script and the name of the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it helps if I add `!#/bin/bash` at the beginning of the file... Then the name of the script appears in the `ps` report.